# Need to call a javascript function on checked changed property of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, c#-4.0

I was trying call a function on check change of checkbox, but the method I written in javascript doesn's calling. I am trying with following code
calling onchange on checkbox

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onchange="fun();" />
```

function calling in javascript

```
function fun() { }
```

Debugger is not going thrue this function.
Also can we do it by jQuery easily?
Thanks,

Comment: "Also can we do it by jQuery easily?" - yes, it's one of the things jQuery knows how to do. You can also do it in native javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$('#CheckBox1').on('change', fun);
```

plain JS

```
document.getElementById('CheckBox1').addEventListener('change', fun, false);
```

**EDIT:**

If the javascript code comes before the DOM element is created, you'll need some sort of DOM ready function, like window.onload in plain JS. jQuery uses document ready, and a shortcut for that is :

```
$(function() {
    $('#CheckBox1').on('change', fun);
});
```

Comment: @JanDvorak - Yes, for supporting older IE versions the standard check for `attachEvent` should be used.

Comment: I am trying with jQuery but crashed and giving error- "Microsoft JScript runtime error: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Comment: You need to wrap jQuery code in document ready, and include the library on you site. That error message tells you that you either did not include the jQuery file correctly, or you forgot the wrapping function, see updated answer.

Comment: I have tried with it, and now it giving error- "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'on'"

Comment: That error message means you are using a really outdated version of jQuery. on() is supported from version 1.7, and right now you should be using version 1.8.3 ?

Comment: Ohh ya I was using 1.6.2 version, I have changed it to 1.8.0 now its working fine...Thanks a lot..!!